# Interface Builder accessing super class attribute

Tags: iphone, interface-builder

I have a class A, and B like these:

```
@interface A : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>{
   UITableView tv;
}
@end


@interface B : A {

}
@end
```

My question is: "In the interface builder, how can I link the table view **tv** to the nib of class B?"

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In class A declarration change

```
UITableView tv;
```

to

```
IBOutlet UITableView* tv;
```

Works for me.